# Cefsharp doesn't load online flash games

Tags: flash, cefsharp

I'm creating a personal app that can run any flash games both online and offline. I've been using CefSharp v75.1.143 with Pepperflash plugin. I tried different offline flash games and it worked as intended. But when I tried to play an online flash game, specifically Adventure Quest Worlds, the game gets stuck at 100%. I can't find out the cause because debug.log doesn't show any error at all.

The code that I've been using is:

```
private void InitializeChromium()
        {
            CefSettings settings = new CefSettings();
            string PepPath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), @"resources\plugins\pepflashplayer.dll");
            string PepVer = "29.0.0.171";

            settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("ppapi-flash-path", PepPath);
            settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("ppapi-flash-version", PepVer);
            settings.CefCommandLineArgs["plugin-policy"] = "allow";

            Cef.Initialize(settings, performDependencyCheck: true, browserProcessHandler: null);
            chromeBrowser = new ChromiumWebBrowser(@"aq.com/game"); //The game that I'm testing

            Controls.Add(chromeBrowser);
            chromeBrowser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

        }
```

I tried changing pepflashplayer to an older version but it doesn't work.
I also tried adding `settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("disable-web-security", "1");` and `settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("allow-file-acccess-from-files", "1");` but still gets the same error.

Is there something wrong with my code?

Comment: Try putting any offline game you have (and perfectly running offline) online. If the problem with your part of this system, the game won't run. If it does run online as well, then the problem is within that game that doesn't want to run for you.

Comment: You can check for errors in DevTools, https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/Trouble-Shooting#javascript-debugging version 86 Was the last to support flash, you might want to try a newer version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got it working. The reason why that happens is because Flash/PepperFlash doesn't trust the swf file, causing for it to block all incoming/outgoing connections.

To make it recognize as trusted by flash, you need to place a text (.txt) or config (.cfg) file in `C:\Users\{USER}\AppData\Roaming\Macromedia\Flash Player\#Security\FlashPlayerTrust` (directory depends on your os and/or flash version). Inside the text contains a path where the directory of the swf is located. It can be also a path to the file itself.

For more detailed explanation, you can refer [here](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7c85.html).